# How to load all data when splash screen loads?

Tags: android

I am working on a application, I want to load all the data from web services when application launch at first time. I have around 20 activities in my application, and currently I am successful in loading data and storing it in sqlite database when user requests for particular activity. Instead of doing so, I want to load all the data at the time of application initialisation for the first time. How can I load multiple activity data when application launches ?
Need help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all the data from webservices of around 20 activities at the time of application launches i.e. on the splash screen. And store that data into the sqlite database. Then, for each activity, fetch particular data from the sqlite database.